How does one deploy Hyperledger Fabric components separately using Minifabric on different machines?
While working on setting up a Hyperledger Fabric network using Minifabric, one had successfully used Minifabric to bring up the entire network as a whole, but now, it is required to deploy the components (such as Orderer, Peer, CA, etc.) individually on different machines.
Here are the steps one had tried so far:

Initialized the Minifabric environment using minifab setup.
Attempted to deploy individual components using commands like minifab up and specifying various options, but faced issues with component dependencies and configurations. Additionally, I could not find a command that specifically allows for bringing up a node separately.

Below is one's current network configuration:
cas:
  - "ca1.org0.example.com"
  - "ca1.org1.example.com"
peers:
  - "peer1.org0.example.com"
  - "peer1.org1.example.com"
orderers:
  - "orderer1.example.com"
settings:
  ca:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
  peer:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
  orderer:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
netname: "mysite"

It is expected to have each of these nodes running on separate machines but within the same network. Also, one wants to perform an experiment that requires this setup.
Having read through the Minifabric documentation and searched through various questions and discussions, one hasn't found a clear guide or example on how to achieve this.
Has anyone successfully deployed individual components using Minifabric on separate machines? If so, could you please provide a detailed step-by-step guide or point me towards the relevant documentation?
